# Pipe echo of change the current directory to sh does not work

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface, echo, concurrentdictionary

If I do the code:

```
echo "printf 'working'" | sh
```

the code prints out `working`

but when I want to change the current directory this way:

```
echo "cd ../" | sh
```

the current directory isn't changed.

Do you know the reason behind that behavior?
do you know how to echo `cd` command to `sh` in a working way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "cd /" | sh
```

actually creates 2 new processes:  echo, and sh.  The sh process most probably does change the directory, but then just exits.  You could test this by

```
echo "cd ../; touch Jimmix_was_here" | sh
ls -l ../Jimmix_was_here
```

which should show empty file `Jimmix_was_here` file, with current timestamp (if you had write permission to the parent directory; otherwise the first command would throw error.)

There's no way to change current directory of a process from within a child; after all if it was possible, it would be a security hole!

Note: this reminds me of a seemingly paradoxical fact: why `/bin/cd` exists?

Note 2: Try `pstree | cat` and find both pstree and cat--they are siblings!

Comment: "why /bin/cd exists?" Very good question. I've never thought about that. But there seems to be an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command) TL;DR POSIX compliance; exit status; automounting a directory